# Rubocop warning SymbolProc in blueprinter serializer custom field in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization, rubocop

I have a Blueprinter serializer with a custom field (see screenshot)

[image]

```
field :score_details do |user|
  user.score_details
end
```

and you can see a Rubocop warning for this block and I can't make it disappear. I read the Rubocop doc : [SymbolProc](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/SymbolProc) but without success..

To explain in details: I have a User model in which I include a concern in order to calculate a score. In this concern I have 1 method (with no parameter) which returns a simple integer.
Finally, I use this method in my `UserSerializer` in order to render my score to my frontend.

Here is my include in my User model:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include UserScoresConcern
end
```

Here is my concern:

```rb
module UserScoresConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def score_details
      # this method return 45 for example
      calculate_user_score_details
    end
  end
end
```

What can I do to fix this warning? Has anyone ever encountered the same issue?

Thanks

Comment: field :score_details (&:score_details)

Comment: Please include code as text and not screenshots of your editor/terminal, etc. They are not indexable, searchable or accessible.

Comment: @Deepak Mahakale `field :score_details (&:score_details)` does not work 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `field` method takes a block that will be called with 2 arguments the `object` and the `local_options`. [See `BlockExtractor#extract`](https://github.com/procore/blueprinter/blob/d026b9cb863abb0fb4115803306bcd272608f646/lib/blueprinter/extractors/block_extractor.rb#L5)

Your issue is that your block ignores the fact that 2 arguments are provided and thus Rubocop believes you can use `Symbol#to_proc` (because it thinks there is only a single argument sent to the block); however if you acknowledge the second argument this warning will go away.

```
field :score_details do |user,_| 
  user.score_details
end
```

Here we acknowledge the second argument using the underscore character `_`. This is a standard convention to show that we do not intend to use this argument.

Another way to determine the method is calling your block with 2 arguments is to use a lambda instead

```
field :score_details, &->(user) {user.score_details}
```

This will result in `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1))` because the lambda is only expecting 1 argument but there are 2 arguments being passed in. This is one of the distinct differences between a standard `Proc` and a lambda (which is a "special" type of `Proc`).

The error you experienced [Commented Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69104329/rubocop-warning-symbolproc-in-blueprinter-serializer-custom-field-in-rails/69168811#comment122135519_69104397) *"wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)"* can be easily recreated to show what is actually occurring

```
def example
  yield "10",2
end 

example(&:to_s)
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0))
```

This because when using `Symbol#to_proc` in this instance it will evaluate as `"10".to_s(2)` but `String#to_s` does not take any arguments just like `User#score_details` thus causing `user.score_details(local_options)` to fail in the same fashion.

Comment: Nice catch. I didn’t know that extra args are forwarded to the method. I will definitely take advantage of it in the future :)

Comment: @fralps please mark this as the correct answer

Comment: @rewritten yeah it's one of those underutilized hidden features like `enum_for`

Answer (score 1):

You just have to write it as

```rb
field :score_details, &:score_details
```

The reason for it is that the `&` prefix operator takes its argument (in this case, a symbol), calls its `to_proc` method, ensure it is actually a proc, and then use it as block argument.

For symbols, the `to_proc` method returns a one-argument proc that is equivalent to the `__send__` method on the argument. That is:

```rb
# these are functionally equivalent:
:my_symbol.to_proc
->(arg) { arg.__send__(:my_symbol) }
->(arg) { arg.my_symbol }
```

The difference is that `Symbol#to_proc` is arguably more optimized.

Comment: Yes the warning disappear but I have a 500 `wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)`

Comment: @fralps the proc returned by `Symbol#to_proc` expects exactly one argument, so the exception is raised somewhere else. Can you share the backtrace (at lest the top of it)?

Comment: ` app/serializers/user_serializer.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UserSerializer>'`

Comment: Then it's very likely that `user.score_details` itself expects an argument.

Comment: `score_details` is a method inside a concern for my user model and it does not need an argument

Comment: Can you update the original question with the complete serializer? and the first2-3 lines of exception with the corresponding parts of code (including how `score_details` is implemented)

Comment: I updated my question, I hope it's clearer for you..

Comment: Your last section *"these are functionally equivalent:"* is incorrect. For Example `a = :to_i.to_proc; b = ->(arg) { arg.__send__(:to_i)}` Then `a.("10", 2) #=> 2` and `b.("10",2) #=> ArgumentError`. The functional equivalent to `Symbol#to_proc` would be more like `->(arg,*rest) { arg.public_send(:my_symbol,*rest)}`

Answer (score 0):

I manage to make it work but without a custom field.

I add my method directly into my fields list like that and it works:

```rb
fields  :email,
        :score_details
```